# How can I add a token to Challenge Based Authenticator in Restlet?

Tags: security, https, access-token, restlet, restlet-2.0

I am developing a Restlet API. I have the server running and a test client code that authenticates itself using HTTP_BASIC under Challenge Based Authentication mechanism.

After a user has provided the correct credentials(username & password), I would like to generate a token in server side and send it to the client which it has to attach in all requests that follow.

How can I add the token?

I couldn't find enough documentation on this issue. I was thinking maybe to add it to the ChallengeReqest and the client then will attach it somewhere in ChallengeResponse on every request that follows. But I'm not sure how that is possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can have a look at this post that typically describes this issue: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/.

To pass a token with Restlet, you could leverage the OAuth challenge response with the challenge scheme `BEARER`, as described below:

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://...");

ChallengeResponse cr = new ChallengeResponse(
                    ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER);
cr.setRawValue(token.getAccessToken());

clientResource.setChallengeResponse(cr);
```

This will add the token within the header `Authorization`.

At the server side, we need to implement a Restlet verifier that will extract the token from the request and check if it's valid. Something like that:

```
public class TokenBasedVerifier implements Verifier {
    public int verify(Request request, Response response) {
        ChallengeResponse cr = request.getChallengeResponse();
        String token = cr.getRawValue();
        checkToken(token);
    }
}
```

This class can be configured within routing like this:

```
ChallengeAuthenticator guard = new ChallengeAuthenticator(
     getContext(), ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER, "testRealm");
TokenBasedVerifier verifier = new TokenBasedVerifier();
guard.setVerifier(verifier);

Router router = (...)
guard.setNext(router);
```

You have a look at the following class for more hints in the extension `org.restlet.ext.oauth`:

- Class `ProtectedClientResource` for the client side
- Class `TokenVerifier` for the server side

Hope it will help you,
Thierry